# MVC SignalR app acting as a hub for a WPF app

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, signalr

If I build a website that has a built-in SignalR hub (single IIS site), such as http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc,
can I use other apps to connect to it, such as WPF or whatnot.  My impression is that I would need a standalone SignalR hub that runs on its own, on a different port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same host. If you use windows auth you need to setup the credentials on the WPF client.

You can look at my WPF demo that uses Caliburn Micro for MVVM and my SignalR library for a MVVM/Aggregation friendly way of using SignalR

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.DotNet